# How do I get a variable in one function to another function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, python-3.6

Code                                                                                                                                                                                                         :

```
def create_Table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer(name TEXT NOT NULL, accountNo INTEGER NOT NULL, balance INTEGER NOT NULL)')
    conn.commit()

def data_insert():
    name = str(input("Enter your name: "))
    accountNo = random.randrange(2016000,2025000)
    balance = int(input("Enter your initial deposit: $"))
    if balance>0:
        print("You have successfully opened an account, your account number is: ",accountNo)
    else:
        print("Incorrect initial deposit, Please deposit $1 or more")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO customer VALUES(?, ?, ?)",(name, accountNo, balance)) 


def authentication():
    user_Id_Input = int(input("Enter your account number: "))
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE accountNo = ?",(user_Id_Input,))
    return user_Id_Input
    conn.commit()

def user_balance():
    authentication()
    if c.fetchall() is not None:
        c.execute("SELECT balance FROM customer WHERE accountNo = ? "(user_Id_Input,))
        data = c.fetchone()
        print("Your balance is: $",data)
    else:
        print("You have entered an incorrect account number.")
    conn.commit()
```

I want to get the variable `user_Id_Input` from `def authentication():` to `def user_balance():`. Even though I have coded `authentication()` in `def user_balance():` I still cannot get the variable to the `balance()` function.

Comment: you are returning `user_Id_Input` from `authentication()` but not capturing the returned value in `user_balance()`. use `user_Id_Input = authentication()` in `user_balance()`. also you should move `conn.commit()` before `return` statement in `authentication()`

Answer (score 0):

You either pass it as an argument or make it globally accessible. Have a look at some reading on the notion of scope.

https://www.smallsurething.com/how-variable-scope-works-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `user_Id_Input` from `authentication()` but not capturing the returned value in `user_balance()`. That is why the returned value is lost. Use -

```
user_Id_Input = authentication()
```

in `user_balance()`. That way you can capture the returned value.

If you want to avoid return but still want to access `user_Id_Input` from other functions, you can make `user_Id_Input` global. Then you can access it via proper method.

Now I want to point out some other areas of your code which you may like to improve. First, you should move `conn.commit()` before `return` statement in `authentication()`. In `data_insert()` you also want to do `commit` at then end of the function. One more thing, you might want to consider adding a primary key for your table `customer`. In `data_insert()` if user provided negative or 0 value for deposit, you are warning user about the invalid balance but that do not stop your code from inserting with same value.

Comment: I did that but I get an error saying : `c.execute("SELECT balance FROM customer WHERE accountNo = ? "(user_Id_Input,))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: Because you missed a comma. It should be `c.execute("SELECT balance FROM customer WHERE accountNo = ? ", (user_Id_Input,))`

Comment: @enochronchi, does that fix your problem?